# Which CMS can use Oracle as database?

Tags: database, oracle, wordpress, drupal, joomla

My client has an Oracle 11g installed and want migrate the company site to a CMS that uses the oracle.

Answer (score 4):

There is an "experimental" [Oracle driver](http://drupal.org/project/oracle) module for Drupal. From what I understand, adding support for new database backends is easier in Drupal 7 because it uses [PDO](http://drupal.org/requirements/pdo). For instance, Drupal 7 includes support for SQLite in core.

I did some quick searching and didn't find anything equivalent for WordPress or Joomla, the other two CMS packages you included in the tags.

Answer (score 0):

There is this [post](http://fabrikar.com/forums/showthread.php?t=16799) on the forum for the [Fabrik joomla extension](http://fabrikar.com/index.php) extension that describes a patch to allow the component to connect to an Oracle database. It was contributed by a user, and I personally cannot vouch for it, however.